# Ambiguous Entry System.Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

Im getting a error when im parsing a method trough system.reflection:

> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException

```
typeof(Graphics).GetMethod("DrawRectangle").Invoke(g, new object[] {
     Pens.Red, new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 50)
});
```

however it works nice when im parsing it trough the compiler

```
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(200,200,100,50));
```

is there a way to specify which method i want to call?

Comment: just want to know, is method public or private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Graphics.DrawRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#overloads) has 3 different overloads, so it is impossible to find concrete one via `GetMethod` just by name, you can specify parameter types for desired overload in `GetMethod` call:

```
typeof(Graphics).GetMethod("DrawRectangle", new[] {typeof(Pen), typeof(Rectangle)})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different overload for DrawRectangle.

Try something like this.

```
var args = new object[] { Pens.Red, new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 50) };
 var r = 
 typeof(Graphics).GetMethod("DrawRectangle",System.Type.GetTypeArray(args));
 r.Invoke(g, args);
```